# Any idea why the 2nd case not working in jq command?

Tags: json, jq

I thought I had done a lot on jq command.  But why the following 2 command, one is working, and the other fails ?

**Working case:**
echo '{"destinations": {"results": [{"sessions": "16903"}]}}' | jq '.destinations'

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "sessions": "16903"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Broken Case:**

echo '{"pre-destinations": {"results": [{"sessions": "16903"}]}}' | jq '.pre-destinations'

```
jq: error: destinations/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
.pre-destinations
jq: 1 compile error
```

The root cause is I was using a **'-'** in the key value, but why it fails ?

Jack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the key named ".pre-destinations", the hyphen is regarded as a special character, so you would have to quote the key name, e.g.

```
jq '".pre-destinations"'
```

or more robustly (with respect to variations between different versions of jq):

```
jq '["pre-destinations"]'
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips. other than hyphen, any other special character I should be aware of ? I have the JSON response from my client side, and try to extract some values that I am looking for.  But I don't have control what their general request body looks like.  It breaks my script.

Comment: Only alphanumeric characters plus the underscore can be used in the abbreviated form.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer doesn't work for any version of jq I've tried. This is the only way I could get it to work:

```
echo '{"pre-destinations": {"results": [{"sessions": "16903"}]}}' | \
    jq '. | to_entries | .[] | select (.key == "pre-destinations") | .value'
```